# ssl certificate IIS - self signed

Tags: ssl, iis, https

I have web api hosted on one of our windows server we have not purchased ssl certificate. I want to use self signed or free ssl server for the particular API. I have generated a self signed certificate on IIS. Accessing the page with https I am getting **"This page can’t be displayed"** error. To configure HTTPS I have followed these steps:

- Selected server from IIS.
- Go to server certificates
- Create Self Signed Certificate
- Added a friendly name
- Selected Personal.(and tried out web hosting too)
- Select site
- Go to bindings
- Add new bindings
- Enter host name select certificate from drop down and select HTTPS.

I have also tried "Certify the Web" desktop app to generate the certificate. It is also giving the same result. Moreover, I have checked 443 port is open on server and its listening to the requests. API is working fine with HTTP.

Specs: 
Windows Server 2012 R2, 
IIS Version 6.2 (Build 9200)

Can anyone recommend a solution to resolve this?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html Run some basic diagnostics so that details can be revealed.

Comment: could you share your IIS site binding detail? did you bind the hostname in your host file? make sure your site is not stopped. provide the error snapshot.